# What is the general solution to $2n d^2+4= v^4$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to generate solutions to the equation
$$2nd^2 + 4 = v^4.$$

Is there a general way to find solutions?

I understand how to solve similar equations — for example, the equation

$$2n(a^2) + b^2 = c^2$$

has solutions
\begin{align}
a &= 2vt, \\
b &= v^2 - 2nt^2, \\
c &= v^2+2n t^2.
\end{align}

I found [this writeup](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/003), but I am not sure I understand it. Specifically I don't understand the symbol $O$ with $2$ dots above it and what operation is involved.

PS the formatting on this site is seriously broken. It shouldn't take 15 minutes to add a newline.

PPS in english. There exists an equality where $d$ raised to the second power is multiplied by $2n$ and added to $4$ and thus being equal to $v$ raised to the fourth power. I am looking for the general solution where all solutions can be expressed at once using variables. I am interested in rational values $d$ and $v$ for a given integer $n$.

Comment: This is very hard to read. Over in the help section, there are tips on formatting mathematics on this site.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Note that by subtracting $16$ from both sides and factoring, your equation becomes
\begin{align}
2(nd^2-6) &= (v-2)(v+2)(v^2+4).
\end{align}
Clearly, $v$ is even, say $v=2w$ for an integer $w$. Now
\begin{align}
2(nd^2-6) &= (2w-2)(2w+2)(4w^2+4)  \\
nd^2 - 6 &= 8(w-1)(w^2+1).
\end{align}

We have the obvious solution $(n,d,w)=(6,1,1)$, corresponding to Gerry Myerson's observation about $n=6$, $d=1$, $v=2$. It's also clear that for $w \ne 1$, we have $d$ odd, since otherwise $6 \equiv 0\!\pmod{4}$ which is impossible. Write $d=2c+1$, so that
\begin{align}
8(w-1)(w^2+1) &= n(2c+1)^2 - 6 \\
&= 4nc^2+4nc+(n-6).
\end{align}
Now $n = 4m+2$ for some integer $m$, and
\begin{align}
8(w-1)(w^2+1) &= 4(4m+2)c^2+4(4m+2)c+((4m+2)-6)  \\
(w-1)(w^2+1) &= (2m+1)c^2+(2m+1)c+m-1.
\end{align}
Solving this as a quadratic in $c$ forces
$$(2m+1)(4w^3-4w^2+4w-2m+1)$$
to be a square. So each is a square, or $2m+1=gp^2$ and $4w^3-4w^2+4w-2m+1=gq^2$ for some integers $(g,p,q)$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. You can take it from there, I'm sure.

Answer (score -3):

Never mind I figured out the part I was asking about.
Turns out it was easier than formatting a newline on this site.

$d=2 (p^3 q + (2n) p q^3)$,
$v=p^2 + (2n) q^2$

Subject to

$4=p^4 - (2n)^2 q^4$

Comment: $4=p^4-(2n)^2q^4=(p^2+2nq^2)(p^2-2nq^2)$. There's no solution if $n=0$. We may then assume $n$ is positive. But then $p^2+2nq^2\ge p^2+2q^2\gt4$ unless $(p,q)$ is one of $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, or $(0,0)$. And these don't work. So, if your calculations are correct, there are no solutions. But wait --- $n=6$, $d=1$, $v=2$ works. So, something is wrong.

Comment: "Formatting a newline on this site" is actually quite easy.

Comment: Please don't vandalize posts on this site, Darrin.